# O notation, Duelling Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, big-o

How would i find the smallest positive integer for which algorithm B out-performs algorithm A?

```
A = n/4, B = 8×log2n(Base of 2 Not 2n)

A = n^3/10, B = 5×n2

A = n^2/2, B = 20×n×log2n(Base of 2 Not 2n)

A = n^4, B = 16×n2×n
```

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me find answers to these :)

Comment: difference between power and coefficient is indistinct

Comment: What is `n2` in `16×n2×n` ? Did you mean `n^2` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [math.se] question.

Comment: ohh yes.. I apologize;; I just had difficult time understanding the question..I didn't realize it would be a mathematics question. and i can't close the question at the moment since I have an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really asking whether `A(n) > B(n)`.

It is simple to answer to those questions: 
**solve the inequalities for `n`**

You can also plot the two functions on the same plane and see how they behave and what is the relation among them. The following is for the first of your questions. As you can see it is clear from the graph when one outperforms the other.[image: As for the first of your questions]

For instance `n^3/10 > 5×n^2` solves for `n>50`

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%5E3%2F10+%3E+5%C3%97n2

**Consider asking this kind of questions on https://math.stackexchange.com/**

Hope this helps

Comment: hahaha yes.. I just figured;; sorry about this non-programming related question. and thank you! your answer made me realize that I was on the right track! :)